# Why does /var/log/wtmp becomes so huge? How to inspect wtmp files?

Tags: login, logs

Just noticed some 640MB wtmp file in a virtual container (Ubuntu Hardy).

```
# last -n 10000 -f /var/log/wtmp.1|wc -l
384
# ls -hl /var/log/wtmp.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp 641M 21. Sep 07:49 /var/log/wtmp.1
```

logrotate was not installed (I just did that and forced rotating).

Are there records in there not being displayed by `last` (which should show the last 1000 entries, but apparently there are only 384).

From quickly skimming the `wtmp/utmp` man page, it does not look like a single entry should use about 1,6MB.

Is there another program besides `last` to inspect these files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`logrotate` was a good idea.

Like any regular file, wtmp could have been "sparse" (cf. lseek(2) "holes" and `ls -s`) which can show a extreme file size that actually occupies little disk. How did the hole get there, if it was a hole? `getty(8)` and friends could have had a bug. Or a system crash and fsck repair could have caused it.

If you are looking to see the raw contents of wtmp, `od` or `hd` are good for peeking at binaries and have the happy side effect of showing long runs of empty as such.

Unless it recurs, I wouldn't give it much more thought. A marginally competent intruder would do a better job than that, the contents aren't all that interesting, and little depends on them.

Comment: The file does not appear to be sparse: here is the beginning of the new file (already 23MB): http://pastebin.com/NFtnyUJU

If I understand this correctly, it looks like a bunch of logins? (6=LOGIN_PROCESS).

The machine is a OpenVZ container, running BOINC (distributed computing), so this might be just as expected.


There was another machine with a huge wtmp file (phpmyadmin, web server), where the output of `hd` looks more odd: http://pastebin.com/1UtxYudE

Answer (score 7):

Just to help others which might find this useful...

> Is there another program besides `last` to inspect these files?

Yes, try `utmpdump`.

```
$ utmpdump /var/log/wtmp
```

Answer (score 2):

If you doubt the wtmp might have holes you could get rid of them with `cp --sparse` if you have new enough coreutils, or with `fallocate --dig-holes` if you use yet not released util-linux 2.25 version. Perhaps more practical approach is to repack the wtmp.

```
utmpdump /var/log/wtmp | utmpdump -r > /tmp/newtmp
ls -l /var/log/wtmp /tmp/newtmp # if significantly smaller
chown root:root /tmp/newtmp
chmod 0554 /tmp/newtmp
mv /tmp/newtmp /var/log/wtmp
```

And if even then the file is rather large then just rotate & compress.

```
mv /var/log/wtmp{,.1}
gzip -9 /var/log/wtmp.1
```

Answer (score 0):

`utmp` is usually sparse - its records are indexed by the major+minor device numbers of the controlling terminal of the session. This ensures that "stale" records that fail to be erased during logout will still eventually get overwritten eventually, by the next session on the same terminal.

It can safely be erased each time the system is booted; arguably it should be `/run/utmp` but most distros don't put it there (yet).

`wtmp` is *not* normally sparse, since it's a log that's appended each time there's an event. Since its records are a fixed size, it's easy to read them in reverse order to show "most recent first".

Both files have the same record format, so you can use `less -f /var/log/whatever` to read from a particular file.

It doesn't do any harm if `wtmp` *is* sparse, since the holes just read as all-bytes-zero which is just ignored. However holes may indicate lost records due to an abrupt system shutdown (metadata flushed but content lost).

The `x` suffixed variants have a larger record structure (the old ones didn't have room to hold an entire IPv6 address or a reasonable FQDN), but otherwise behave similarly. Some versions of `last` can read both record structures.